# Skyrim Is there any mod or command to reset all towns?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I downloaded the open cities mod, it was a little laggy so i unninstaled it, but a lot of npcs are stuck under the towns like whiterun, is there any mod or console command to reset the towns without having to create a new character or reset all the quests?
Or a command to move all the npcs in that city to you instead of moving one by one

Comment: You might be out of luck. I don't know of anything.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use this mod [Skyrim Save Cleaner](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/31724/?) because it has this feature: 
`Cleaning up CELL data (not homes you own)`, which might be helpful for you.

Comment: God damn it, the nexus site is down, but i will try it later, thanks